# Using a MethodInterceptor to wrap calls to protected method

Tags: spring, spring-aop, aopalliance

I would like to use XML based Spring configuration to wrap calls to a protected method in a 3rd party class. I have wired up some spring classes from `org.springframework.aop.support`. It works for public methods, but it fails for protected ones:

```
<bean id="sampleAutoProxyCreator" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
<property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
<property name="beanNames">
    <list>
        <value>thrirdPartyBean</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="interceptorNames">
    <list>
        <value>sampleAdvisor</value>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="sampleMethodNamePointcut" class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcut">
    <property name="mappedNames">
        <list>
            <value>publicMethodThatWorks</value>
            <value>protectedMethodThatDoesNotWork</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="sampleAdvice" class="sample.MyMethodInterceptor" />
<bean id="sampleAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="pointcut" ref="sampleMethodNamePointcut" />
    <property name="advice" ref="sampleAdvice" />
</bean>
```

How can I tweak this to work with protected methods ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093894/aspectj-pointcut-for-annotated-private-methods. You would need to use AspectJ for that.

Comment: What is the underlying problem ? I mean technically, access should be no problem when the proxy is generated the package of the proxied class.

Answer (score 0):

As the [linked question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093894/aspectj-pointcut-for-annotated-private-methods) in the comments states, Springs AOP proxies can only apply to `public` methods.

With JDK proxies, this isn't possible because the proxy only has your target object's interface types so you can only interact with it through its `public` methods (remember that all methods declared in an interface are `public`).

With GGLIB proxies, because the proxy does have the target object's class type, you can interact with its `protected` methods. I would think for reasons of consistency between proxying mechanisms they would not allow it.