# Replace Private Method of Spring Bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-ioc

i have requirement to replace private method of spring bean, can i achieve through spring replace.

My Code :
    Replacer Class :

```
public class PrivateCarRep extends Car implements MethodReplacer{

@Override
public Object reimplement(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args) throws 
Throwable {

    // new property of Car.breaks() method.
    System.out.println("New  privateBreaksIs Done from Shiv");

    return obj;
}

}
```

Car.java

```
package org.websparrow.beans;

public class Car {
private void privateBreaks() {
    System.out.println("Old car break. privateBreaks");
}
}
```

My Spring Configuration:

```
<bean id="PrivateCarRep" class="org.websparrow.beans.PrivateCarRep"/>

<bean id="car" class="org.websparrow.beans.Car">
    <replaced-method name="privateBreaks" replacer="PrivateCarRep" />
</bean>
```

Dear All,
 i already know that i can't replace private method through spring replacer but **is there any workaround for this in spring..**

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `PrivateCarRep` as a bean:

```
<bean id="privateCarReplacer" class="com.xx.yy.zz.PrivateCarRep" />

<bean id="car" class="org.websparrow.beans.Car">
    <replaced-method name="privateBreaks" replacer="privateCarReplacer" />
</bean>
```

Comment: that i have already define still its not working. I am asking to change the access modifier of method from private to public so i can replace the method through method replacer

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  I think you may need to use AspectJ to intercept the calls to the private method, and call your replacement, instead... This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093894/aspectj-pointcut-for-annotated-private-methods

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do that,I thing the method should be be protected or public.